# Changing GTK Theme From Within GTK Application

Tags: themes, gtk

I have an application written in GTK and I was just playing around with theme changes via GTK Inspector. I even explored other themes available from GitHub. Is it possible to give an end user of my application the ability to change the theme from within the software? I know that the GTK_THEME environment variable can be set for the application when it is executed, and I also found that the theme can be changed from within the code (using the default C language bindings) using:

```
setenv("GTK_THEME", "Ambiance", 1);
```

But this only works if this variable is set prior to running `gtk_init().` Trying to do so afterwards is not successful. Is there any possible way that I can allow the user to change the theme and have it take affect immediately (as is done via GTK Inspector)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I answered my own question by going to the GTK Inspector source code to see how they did it. I am using GTK 3.24 so this will look a little different if you are using GTK4 (deprecations):

```
GtkSettings *settings;
gchar *theme_name = "Ambiance";

settings = gtk_settings_get_default();
g_object_set(settings, "gtk-theme-name", theme_name, NULL);
```

The theme name can be dynamically allocated from somewhere, I just did it to test that it works. Note that this will not work if you have the GTK_THEME environment variable set.